# Deep learning accuracy changes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Every time I change the dataset, it gives a different accuracy. Sometimes it gives 97%, 50%, and 92%. It is a text classification. Why does this happen? The other 95% comes from 2 datasets that are the same size and give almost the same result.

```
#Split DatA
X_train, X_test, label_train, label_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
                                                           
#Size of train and test data:
print("Training:", len(X_train), len(label_train))
print("Testing: ", len(X_test), len(label_test))

#Function defined to test the models in the test set
def test_model(model, epoch_stop):
   model.fit(X_test
             , Y_test
             , epochs=epoch_stop
             , batch_size=batch_size
             , verbose=0)
   results = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
   return results
#############3

maxlen = 300
#Bidirectional LSTM model
embedding_dim = 100
dropout = 0.5
opt = 'adam'
####################
#embed_dim = 128 #dimension of the word embedding vector for each word in a sequence 
lstm_out = 196  #no of lstm layers
lstm_model = Sequential()
#Adding dropout
#lstm_model.add(LSTM(lstm_out, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))##############################
lstm_model = Sequential()
lstm_model.add(layers.Embedding(input_dim=num_words, 
                          output_dim=embedding_dim, 
                          input_length=X_train.shape[1]))

#lstm_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_out, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))) 
#lstm_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(lstm_out, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2)))
#lstm_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)))
lstm_model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)))
lstm_model.add(layers.GlobalMaxPool1D())
#Adding a regularized dense layer
lstm_model.add(layers.Dense(32,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.001),activation='relu'))
lstm_model.add(layers.Dropout(0.25))
lstm_model.add(Dense(3,activation='softmax'))
lstm_model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics = ['accuracy'])
print(lstm_model.summary())

#TRANING 

history = lstm_model.fit(X_train, label_train,
                   epochs=4,
                   verbose=True,**strong text**
                   validation_data=(X_test, label_test),
                   batch_size=64)
loss, accuracy = lstm_model.evaluate(X_train, label_train, verbose=True)
print("Training Accuracy: {:.4f}".format(accuracy))
loss_val, accuracy_val = lstm_model.evaluate(X_test, label_test, verbose=True)
print("Testing Accuracy:  {:.4f}".format(accuracy_val))
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

ML models will base their predictions on the data previously trained on, it is only natural that the outcome will differ in case the training data is changed. Also it might be the case that a different dataset may perform better using different hyperparameters.

Comment: Thanks , so do u think using using different hyper parameters will improve the accuracy ?

Comment: Yes, you should optimize your hyperparameters for each dataset. Out of interest why exactly do you change datasets?

Comment: Appreciate ur kind help and support , would you support a good resource about  optimize  hyper-parameters, regarding to dataset i was trying to check my model performance in different database so i can kw what coz the low accuracy

Comment: would you recommend what to change in the hyperparmater ? my database has 200,500 row  and gives 50% in this dataset others gives 90%